# TextView is not working in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am facing Problem In `Relative layout`. I set several `textviews` in my XML layout but after running the program, `it will not show the text on emulator/phone`. Before I was thinking, this is the problem of the updated version of android studio. But I had also checked in another computer system with an older android version. I am sharing the XML code with you all. Please Help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/transition_profile"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/round_arrow_back_ios_24_px"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv_help"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/round_help_outline_24_px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv_boss"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:src="@drawable/boss"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_emp_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#262d3d"
        android:letterSpacing="0.02"
        tools:text="Ramesh Singha"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgv_boss"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_boss_profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#6c7383"
        android:letterSpacing="0.02"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_emp_name"
        tools:hint="Field Manager"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_regular"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_tabslides"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_boss_profile_name">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout 
             android:id="@+id/tblyt_profile" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/white"
             android:elevation="6dp" 
             android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:tabIndicatorColor="#0091ea"
             app:tabSelectedTextColor="#0091ea"
             app:tabTextColor="#6c7383"
             tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager 
             android:id="@+id/vpgr_profile"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it's been hidden by your ImageViews. Than check the position and sizes of your TextViews

Comment: use `android:text` instead

Comment: @lambda No, All images are set to their width and height. There is something other problem, i don't know  what is the problem

Comment: Remove all components and add only `Textview` and check the TextView is visible or not..If `TextView`is visible then there is a issues of setting the components in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: try Invalidate cache/Restart

Comment: @JohnJoe Thanks. it is solved by using android:text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `tools:text="Ramesh Singha"` in `textView` and that is used for testing purpose. You should use following options if you want to set text

1. `android:text="Ramesh Singha"`
2. Add in code

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_emp_name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     android:textColor="#262d3d"
     android:letterSpacing="0.02"
     tools:text="Ramesh Singha"
     android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
     android:layout_below="@id/imgv_boss"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />
```

```
TextView userName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_emp_name)
userName.setText("Ramesh Singha")
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Static text**,use

> android:text="Ramesh Singha"

instead of

> tools:text="Ramesh Singha"

**For dynamic text**,use

> .xml File

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_boss_profile_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#6c7383"
    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_emp_name"
    tools:hint="Field Manager"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_regular"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

> .Java File

```
TextView employeeName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_emp_name);
employeeName.setText("Ramesh Singha");
```